# How can I insert the reference ID of one table into another in laravel framework?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

Controller code:

```
public function saveImages(Request $imagesform, $dataId)
{
    if (Input::hasFile('images')) {
        $name = $this->getImageId() . "." . $imagesform->file('images')
                ->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $image = $imagesform->file('images');
        $resize = Image::make($image)
            ->resize(700, 300)
            ->encode($imagesform->file('images')->getClientOriginalExtension());

        $hash = md5($resize->__toString());

        $path = "public/" . $name;
        Storage::put($path, $resize->__toString());

    }

    $insertImages = new photosModel;
    $insertImages->imagesid = $this->getimagesId();
    $insertImages->deviceCategoryId = $dataId;
    $insertImages->uploadedImages = $name;
    //$insertImages->productPricing()->associate($priceInfo->id);
    $insertImages->save();

    echo("success");

    return $this->formImages($dataId);

}
```

This is my controller to store images, with the help of reference id, from `productPriceDetails` table. I want to get that id.

model of table1:

```
class priceInfo extends Model
{
    protected $table = "productPriceDetails";

    protected $connection = "mysql";

    public function photosModel()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\priceInfo');
    }
}
```

This is my productPriceDetails model.I need to use the primary key of this table as foreign key in productPhotos model.

model for table2:

```
class photosModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = "ProductPhotos";

    protected $connection = "mysql";

    protected $primaryKey = 'imagesid';

    public $incrementing = false;

    public function productPricing()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\priceInfo', 'id');
    }
}
```

Here, I have defined the `productPricing()` function;

Comment: Sorry,I ll update that too

Comment: someone,please help me to solve thiss..